# Diferenças entre JSF e JSP

Tags: jsf, java-ee, jsp

Programo web faz pouco tempo (4 meses) e fui direto pra `JSF`, ou seja não estudei nada sobre `JSP`. Comecei a fazer um curso e meu professor meio que menospreza `JSF` falando que possui muitas limitações, que `JSP` é sinônimo de desempenho, etc.

`JSP` é tudo isso mesmo ou essas pessoas, não conhecem `JSF`? Pois como esse mesmo professor meu fala, ele implementa várias coisas na "Mão" enquanto com o `PrimeFaces` tenho tudo pronto. Quais as principais diferenças entre os dois?

Comment: Segue uma ótima resposta do @BalusC no SOen http://stackoverflow.com/a/2097732/5165064

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário @Rafael. Pelo que li o `JSP` roda no servidor, ele pode rodar na maquina do cliente também, de forma que possa reduzir o consumo de processamento do hardware do servidor?

Comment: O que roda do JSP no lado do cliente é o HTML e JavaScript

Comment: Já vi muito "*JSP is deprecated*", mas pelo que eu entendi na [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets.htm#GIEPX) ele é considerado *deprecated* quando o JSF estiver presente. Tanto que na especificação do Java EE8 ele está lá: [JSR 366](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=366).

Comment: JSF Framework component basead lida com as servlets por baixo dos tapetes, JSP podemos trabalhar com os FW action basead, spring,struts,struts2,vraptor, mas se escolher trabalhar na "unha" também é possível. Vou postar uma resposta depois1

Comment: tenta fazer uma manipulação de tabelas em JSP e vê o sofrimento.... depois agradeça por conhecer o JSF

Comment: @PedroLaini quando diz "tabela" está se referindo a um elemento `table` ou aquele código gerado pelo JSF tudo em tabela?

Comment: em JSF, com dataTable, você manipula os dados facilmente... mas em JSP é um sofrimento

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Diferenças entre JSF e JSP

A rigor são tecnologias de escopo distinto: **JSP** é framework* para construir visões enquanto **JSF** é framework* para toda a camada de apresentação, baseado em (mas não limitado a) **MVC**.

Mas na prática JSF substitui o JSP, já que **junto com o JSF 2.0 veio o *Facelets***, este sim com o objetivo de substituir o JSP pois também é um framework* para construção de visões e é todo orientado ao JSF.

<sup>*Na verdade não são frameworks mas sim especificações de frameworks.</sup>

A documentação oficial do Java informa que o JSP é *deprecated*, sendo substituído pelo *Facelets*: [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html).

## Vantagens e desvantagens

JSF e Facelets trouxeram inúmeras vantagens com relação ao modo antigo de fazer (JSP), por exemplo: templates, *composite components*, separação mais rígida entre visão e lógica de apresentação, facilidades AJAX, etc.

Não conheço nenhuma desvantagem do JSF e Facelets em relação ao JSP, não creio que exista algo que possa ser feito com JSP que não possa ser feito com os seus substitutos. As "páginas" JSP na verdade são "compiladas" para código Java tornando-se Servlets, e usando JSF você continua podendo estender a sua aplicação criando seus próprios Servlets. Também não consigo imaginar onde um poderia ter melhor performance que outro.

Então talvez seja o caso de pedir para o seu professor uma lista de desvantagens e então você pode analisá-las e descobrir se são problemas para você e suas aplicações. Eu particularmente duvido que sejam.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta  @Caffé