# JSF é especificação ou framework?

Tags: java, jsf

No GitHub do JavaEE existe o repositório [`javaserverfaces-spec`](https://github.com/javaee/javaserverfaces-spec) que em seu `README.md` diz:

> JavaServer Faces (JSF) is a JCP Standard technology for authoring component based user interfaces on the Java EE platform. This particular GitHub project hosts the official JSF specification issue tracker. There are two implementations of the JSF specification, both of them developed with OSI approved Open Source licenses.

---

Já a [Wiki](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) da tag [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf) diz:

> JavaServer Faces (JSF) é um framework Model-View-Controller normalmente usado para criar aplicações web. Informe sempre: Qual é a versão JSF você está usando; Qual tecnologia você está usando, JSP ou Facelets; Mensagens de erro apresentadas; Cópia mínima do código que possa ser executada.

---

Na Wiki da tag tem um [link](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) do Wikipédia, que diz:

> JavaServer Faces (JSF) é uma especificação Java para a construção de interfaces de usuário baseadas em componentes para aplicações web. Possui um modelo de programação dirigido a eventos, abstraindo os detalhes da manipulação dos eventos e organização dos componentes, permitindo que o programador se concentre na lógica da aplicação.

---

Encontrei também [esse artigo](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/index-090910.html) da Oracle Technology Network de 2005 que diz:

> One of the key advantages of JSF is that it is both a Java Web user-interface standard as well as a framework that firmly follows the Model-View-Controller(MVC) design pattern.

---

Depois de ler esses artigos/fontes não entendi duas coisas:

1. JSF é especificação ou framework?
2. JSF é MVC?

Comment: Relacionada:[Diferenças entre JSF e JSP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81228/28595)

Comment: @diegofm eu vi essa pergunta. O que não entendo é o por que o artigo da OTN diz que JSF pode ser tanto especificação quanto framework MVC (contradizendo a resposta citada)

Comment: @diegofm ainda assim, se a resposta citada estiver certa, precisamos corrigir a wiki da tag, certo?

Comment: @bigown , vi que você construiu a wiki da tag. Se não for lhe atrapalhar, poderia opinar/expôr sua opinião sobre o assunto, por favor? Acho que será muito interessante :)

Comment: Ai não sei te falar, nunca mexi com JSF ou JSP, só relacionei porque vi que eram de temas parecidos.

Comment: O que eu sei é que JSF é algo que deve-se fugir.

Comment: @IgorVenturelli O bigown (assim como qualquer usuário) não vai receber notificação da sua menção se ele não tiver interagido na pergunta, com comentários, votos de fechamento, etc. Estou te avisando pra caso queira falar com ele por outros meios.

Comment: @LINQ nossa! Não sabia... Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Boa pergunta!

Na verdade o JSF por definição trata-se de fato de uma especificação.

Sendo assim, por quê tratamos ele como framework quando nos referimos à ele? Isto ocorre graças ao método de desenvolvimento e distribuição do Java.

**Mas como assim?**

Por padrão quando vamos desenvolver algum programa em Java, a JDK nos fornece um conjunto de ferramentas que são empacotados por padrão na JDK do Java. Contudo tais ferramentas não são o suficiente (ou são muito cruas) para atender todas as necessidades encontradas.

Em virtude desde e de outros motivos, foi criado por volta de 1998 o [Java Community Process](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process), que na verdade trata-se de uma espécie de comunidade que tem como intuito propor, criar e validar novas espeficações para a linguagem Java. Qualquer membro desta comunidade pode implementar alguma destas especificações disponíveis, o que faz com que quando uma especificação seja criada, ela possa possuir diversas implementações diferentes (e com diferentes responsáveis) que fazem basicamente a mesma coisa (com pequenas possíveis diferenças).

**Mas o que isto tem haver com JSF?**

Tudo! JSF atualmente possui duas implementações amplamente utilizadas: Mojarra (Oracle) e MyFaces (Apache).

**Mas espera aí, tem mais um fator a ser considerado quando analisamos isto:**

As implementações não funcionam de forma "standalone" ou "sozinhas", é preciso um servidor de aplicação para rodar estas implementações. É aí que entram os servidores como GlassFish, WildFly e Tomcat. Cada um destes servidores escolhe uma implementação disponível para funcionar, basta procurar na documentação deles que você encontrará esta informação.

Agora se pararmos para analisar, nem a especificação, nem a implementação e nem os servidores de aplicação são de fato um framework. Contudo o conjunto destes fatores, unidos ao produto final, juntamente com sua vasta documentação fazem com que o JSF seja referido à um framework, principalmente pela forma com que os desenvoldedores finais trabalham com ele, e também graças às bibliotecas externas como PrimeFaces, BootsFaces, ButterFaces e etc (estas sim, são frameworks, pois trabalham uma camada acima do JSF puro para facilitar o processo de desenvolvimento).

Sendo assim, fica muito difícil nos referirmos a JSF sem definir ele como um framework. Na minha opinião, quando nos referimos ao JSF de forma mais informal, tanto faz dizer que ele é framework ou especificação, o que importa mesmo é saber um pouco de sua história e usá-lo para nos ajudar com os problemas do dia-a-dia.

Comment: Legal. Então a wiki tag jsf está certa ou errada?

Comment: A wiki tag jsf no ptSO é uma tradução um pouco modificada da tag de mesmo nome do SO (que por sua vez, também define JSF como framework). Sugiro manter a tag como está hoje.